# Is there a way to use out parameter in async method.? If not can anyone suggest me how to return the OUT Parameter from a async method?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I am using the following method :

```
public async Task<SaveStatus> Save(Foo foo,out int param)
{
    .......
    MySqlParameter prmparamID = new MySqlParameter("pParamID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
        prmparamID .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(prmparamID); 
    try
        {
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
            await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

            status = (SaveStatus)Convert.ToInt32(prmReturnValue.Value);

            if (status == SaveStatus.Success)
            {
                if (Common.IsDBValueNotNullOrEmpty(prmParamID))
                {
                    param= Convert.ToInt32(prmParamID.Value);
                }
            }
        }      

    return status;
}
```

I want to return both the status as well as the integer param. Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 11):

You can't have an `out` parameter in an `async` method. Here's more info on why: [Why async methods cannot have ref or out parameters?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2f48a52-e35a-4948-844d-828a1a6deb74/why-async-methods-cannot-have-ref-or-out-parameters)

If you want to return more than a single return value you probably should have a class that holds these values and return it.

If you don't want to create a new class you can use `Tuple`:

```
public async Task<Tuple<SaveStatus, int>> Save(Foo foo)
{
    SaveStatus status;
    int param;

    // ... 

    return Tuple.Create(status, param);
}
```

Comment: How do you retrieve the values `status, param`?

Answer (score -1):

The quick answer is "because people would try to use it".

Technically methods could have `ref` and `out` parameters, but their value could only be set before the first `await`. Because, after that, it's no longer the method the caller called but some compiler generated state machine code running.

Comment: "because people would try to use it" is an answer to which question?